# Error access violation reading 0x0000000a when call fortran dll made by gfortran

Tags: gcc, dll, fortran, gfortran

1.FORTRAN source (main.for)

```
      integer function mysum(a, b)
        !DEC$ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT,STDCALL :: mysum
        !DEC$ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: a, b

        integer a,b

        mysum = a + b

        return

      end function mysum
```

2. make dll

```
gfortran main.for -shared -o fordll.dll
```

3. call dll

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
typedef int(_stdcall * MYSUM)(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    HINSTANCE hLibrary = LoadLibrary("fordll.dll");
    if (hLibrary == NULL)
    {
        cout << "can't find the dll file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    MYSUM fact = (MYSUM)GetProcAddress(hLibrary, "mysum");
    if (fact == NULL)
    {
        cout << "can't find the function file." << endl;
        return -2;
    }

    try
    { 
        cout << fact(a,b);
    }
    catch(...)
    { }

    FreeLibrary(hLibrary); 
    return 0;
}
```

4. ERROR

```
Exception Access Violation reading 0x0000000A
```

why? if the fortran source file is comppiled by Compad Visual fortran or Inter fortran, it works well. However, it doesn't work with gcc or gfortran. What's wrong?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Many more people will see your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using special directives to alter the calling conventions

```
    !DEC$ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT,STDCALL :: mysum
    !DEC$ATTRIBUTES VALUE :: a, b
```

However, these are only valid for the DEC compiler sand its descendant Intel Fortran.

GCC use !GCC$ directives instead. Use them, they are pretty much the same as the DEC ones. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ATTRIBUTES-directive.html#ATTRIBUTES-directive Just change coppy and paste the DEC directives and change `DEC` to `GCC`.

Alternatively, change the code to pass-by-reference and ditch the `VALUE` attribute. The `STDCALL` attribute is relevant for 32-bit Windows only.

---

In modern Fortran it is much better to use

```
integer function mysum(a, b) bind(C,name="mysum")
        
        integer, value :: a, b
```

(ignoring the stdcall issue, which can be just deleted in the C++ code).